# How to Upload/Convert json file to firestore database

Tags: json, google-cloud-firestore

I have almost 10 MB of json data in a file. I want to upload this file to firestore database so i can retrieve from there. I've searched a little but i don't understand how. Really in need of some help. This is the structure of json that i will need to upload.

```
[
{
    "book":"book1",
    "data":
    [
        {
            "chapter":"ch1",
            "topics":
            [
                {
                 "key1":"value1",
                 "key2":"value2",
                 "key3":"value3"
                },
                {
                 "key1":"value1",
                 "key2":"value2",
                 "key3":"value3"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "chapter":"ch2",
            "topics":
            [
                {
                 "key1":"value1",
                 "key2":"value2",
                 "key3":"value3"
                },
                {
                 "key1":"value1",
                 "key2":"value2",
                 "key3":"value3"
                }
            ]
        },
    ]
},
{
    "book":"book2",
    "data":
    [
        {
            "chapter":"ch1",
            "topics":
            [
                {
                 "key1":"value1",
                 "key2":"value2",
                 "key3":"value3"
                },
                {
                 "key1":"value1",
                 "key2":"value2",
                 "key3":"value3"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Firestore does not allow for the uploading of JSON files just yet. Firebase does allow this capability. 
What i did in order to populate tons of data into firestore is to do the following:
1. Upload the JSON file into firebase. 
2. Now create a small front end application that will read the data from firebase and uploads it into the firestore database.

[image]